# How can I change the color of bars in bar graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, colors, histogram

I'd like to create a bar graph where I change the color of some bars.
The code for my bar graph is the following:

```
 y = [0.04552309, -0.001730885, 0.023943445, 0.065564478, 0.032253892, 0.013442562, ...
      -0.011172323, 0.024595622, -0.100614203, -0.001444697, 0.019383706, 0.890249809];
 bar(y)
```

I want the first six bars to be black and the last 6 bars to be blue, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47347611/7328782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to plot them separately (but on the same axes):

```
bar(1:6,y(1:6),'k')
hold on
bar(7:numel(y),y(7:end),'b')
set(gca,'xtick',1:numel(y))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can answer another question concerning this bar graph :). What can I do to get the different values of y on top of the bars? I think I need something like this:

Comment: for i1=1:numel(y)
    text(x(i1),y(i1),num2str(y(i1),'%0.2f'),...
               'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
               'VerticalAlignment','bottom')
end

Comment: But I don't have an x :(. Do you know how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user2971574 The x position in your case is just the i index. So replace `x(i1)` by  `i1`, that is: `for i1=1:numel(y), text(i1,y(i1),num2str(y(i1),'%0.2f'),'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','bottom'), end`

Answer (score 2):

As the answer from [HERE](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99092-how-do-i-define-colors-for-individual-bars-on-my-bar-graph-according-to-their-values-in-matlab) suggests, since the version MATLAB R2017b, you can do so through the *CData* property. You can find more at [THIS](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2019b/matlab/ref/bar.html#d117e81932) documentation page.

Simply put, using the following approach will get you what you need.

```
b = bar(rand(10,1));
b.FaceColor = 'flat';
% Change the color of the second bar. Value assigned defines RGB color value.
b.CData(2,:) = [.5 0 .5];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is adapted from [Bar plot with bars in different colors](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/58971) on MATLAB Central:

```
y= [0.04552309, -0.001730885, 0.023943445, 0.065564478, 0.032253892, 0.013442562,    -0.011172323, 0.024595622, -0.100614203, -0.001444697, 0.019383706, 0.890249809];
for ii=1:12
  h = bar(ii-0.5, y(ii));
  if ii == 1
     hold on
  end
  if ii<=6
     col = 'k';
  else
     col = 'b';
  end    
  set(h, 'FaceColor', col,'BarWidth',0.4) 
end
axis([0 12 -0.2 1])
hold off
```

Comment: Actually, Luis' answer is much simpler and much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

No need to plot separately, here is the simple solution:

```
y= [0.04552309, -0.001730885, 0.023943445, 0.065564478, 0.032253892, 0.013442562,    -0.011172323, 0.024595622, -0.100614203, -0.001444697, 0.019383706, 0.890249809];
figure,
bar(y)

y1 = zeros(1,length(y));
y1(3:5) = y(3:5);
hold on
h = bar(y1)
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'k')
```

[See output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkU09.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Very late as usual, but there is an easy way to 'trick' matlab. 
You first define your colormap (for instance 3 different colors):

```
mycolors = lines(3) % or just specify each row by hand
```

Then you plot your bars in the following way:

```
bar(x,diag(y),'stacked'); % x will be usually defined as x = 1:number_of_bars
colormap(mycolors);
```

That's all. The magic comes from the *diag* function together with the *'stacked'* tag that makes matlab think you have more data (but they are all 0).