# Matlab bar: set colors with colormap(jet) as a function of bar heights

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, colormap

I have 4 different groups of multiple bars. I would like, for each group, to plot each bar with a color which is function of its height value (i.e the value of the concerned bar) with `colormap(jet)`.

For the moment, I have done:

```
h=bar(xpoints(1:4),bpcombined(1:4,:),'grouped','BarWidth',0.5);
colorbar;
colormap(jet);
```

and I get the following figure:

[image]

As you can see, for each bar, its color is not a function of the height : it is just a sequence of different colors (of jet colormap), the same for the 4 groups.

How can I get this dependency, I mean the highest bars would be red and the lowest blue following colormap (jet)?

### Update 1

I tried the solution suggested by `@masei` but I get the following error on Matlab 2016b :

```
No appropriate method, property, or field 'CData' for class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.

Error in test_plot_bar_color (line 17)
    b.CData(k,:) = y_color(k,:);
```

I don't how to circumvent this error.

`@masei` told me to use ‘`FaceColor`’ property but I don't know how to put it on this script.

### Update 2

I tried to apply the suggestion of `@marsei`, i.e plot multiple times the sections of group of bar (and the other groups are set to Nan), like this:

```
  1 clear;
  2 % Data
  3 y = rand(10,4);
  4 % 2D array of nan
  5 y_nan = nan(size(y))
  6 % 1D array by default
  7 y_1d(1:numel(y)) = nan(numel(y),1);
  8 
  9 %Plot
 10 figure('Color', 'w');
 11 title('Bar with height-dependant color');
 12 for k = 1:size(y,2)
 13     % Set default 1D array
 14     y_temp = y_1d;
 15     % Put k-th part of data
 16     y_temp((k-1)*size(y_nan,1)+1:k*size(y_nan,1)) = y(1:size(y_nan,1),k);
 17     % Reshape 1D into 2D for bar
 18     y_final = reshape(y_temp,size(y,2),size(y,1));
 19     % Plot bar
 20     bar_h = bar(y_final,'BarWidth',0.5);
 21     y_color = vals2colormap(y_final(k,:),'jet');
 22     %b.FaceColor = y_color(:,:);
 23     %y_color
 24     bar_child=get(bar_h,'Children');
 25     bar_child.FaceColor = y_color(:,:);
 26     %colormap(y_color);
 27     %set(bar_child,'CData',y_final);
 28     hold on;
 29 end
 30
```

But I get the following error :

```
Field assignment to a non-structure array object.

Error in test_plot_bar_color (line 25)
    bar_child.FaceColor = y_color(:,:);
```

What's wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - An example that uses sorted data (`y = sort(rand(30,10),2)` and `separation_gap = 5`)

[image]

---

You can use a regular bar property called `CData` to assign each bar a color. The colour is computed with the help of `vals2colormap` ([web](https://github.com/vistalab/vistateach/blob/master/cogneuro/tutorial1_timeseries/vals2colormap.m)).

The initial data matrix has 10 rows, that gives 10 groups of bars in regular `bar` plot. At this point, changing the `CData` property for the first bar changes the color of all the first bar (for all groups). You can't dissociate the first bars.

The trick is then to **flatten the matrix** while **inserting NaNs** for group separation. Here, the initial data is `10x4` flatten in a 40 element vector, separated with a single `Nan`. With this, you have a full control over each individual bar (bars are not grouped anymore).

The following graph

[image]

is produced by

```
% data
y = rand(10,4);

% add NaNs (for separation) and flatten
separation_gap = 1; % 2 columns of NaN
y_nan = [y nan(size(y,1), separation_gap)]';
y_flat = [nan(separation_gap,1); y_nan(:)];

%convert values to colomap
y_color = vals2colormap(y_flat, 'jet');

%plot and cange color
figure('Color', 'w');
b = bar(y_flat);%,'grouped'
b.FaceColor = 'flat';
for k = 1:size(y_flat,1)
    b.CData(k,:) = y_color(k,:);
end

title('Bar with height-dependant color');
```

Comment: -@marsei Unfortunately, with your script, I get the following error : " No appropriate method, property, or field 'CData' for class 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'.

Error in plot_from_stack (line 17)
    b.CData(k,:) = y_color(k,:);
" I am using Matlab 2016b

Comment: You can alternatively use ‘FaceColor’ property.

Comment: I don't know how to use 'FaceColor' property with your solution above : the issue seems to come from 'CData' property

Comment: -@marsei could you take a look at my **UPDATE 1** above to help me to work around the CData issue ? regards

Comment: One of the ways is to plot multiple overlaying bar graphs: first one is `[value Nan Nan Nan]`, second one is `[Nan value Nan Nan]`, third one is `[Nan Nan value Nan]`, and fourth `[Nan Nan Nan value]`, with an `hold on` in between the first and second. Each bar graph can be plotted the colour you want.

Comment: -@marsei . Hello, I tried to implement your suggestion, could you take a look please at my UPDATE 2 ?

Comment: You may try to plot each element of this guy `y_1d = [ y(:,1); NaN(2,1); y(:,2); NaN(2,1); y(:,3); NaN(2,1); y(:,4) ]'; ` , including plotting NaN.